# GitHub Pull Requests Between Branches

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My organization is making the transition from SVN to Git (hosted on GitHub) and we have basically adopted the git-flow branching model.

We have been using pull requests to merge between branches.   We use the GitHub web interface to process the merge and close the request.

Pull requests are merged with --no-ff.  So a merge commit will occur in the destination branch.

So....  We merge from **develop** to **master** often - so what happens after the merge is the develop branch will be both *behind* (due to the merge commits not being in master) and *ahead* (due to new work being done in develop).

Over many iterations, we end up with "develop branch is both 23 commits behind and 7 commits ahead of master" - which seems ridiculous.   Should we just not worry about this?  Should we merge manually and not through the GitHuib web interface?

Comment: If you are using "git-flow" could you please tell why you are merging develop to master directly?

Comment: If you care about the merge commits, merge in your CI system with `--ff-only`.  If you just care about the "behind" commits, just merge master back into development every so often with `--ff-only`.  If you don't care, just ignore it.

Comment: @Gökay Gürcan  sometimes we merge from develop (small projects with no real qa cycle), sometimes we use release branches for larger projects, especially with a QA cycle.     We try not to focus on dogma around here ;)    My question still holds for a release branch merge (via pull request) to master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only reason that develop is ever behind is because of merge commits, then you should be able to routinely schedule a sync.

```
git fetch
git checkout develop
git merge --ff-only master
git push
```

If you have some hotfix branch that went in, then the worst case is that the above will fail. However then you're just going to merge without the `--ff-only` tag. That's [perfectly acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418965/strategy-for-keeping-git-feature-branches-up-to-date) and [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602722/how-to-keep-branches-in-sync-when-using-git-flow) (see the comment on the answer).

While it's convenient to use GitHub's pull request system to manage pulls from other remotes, you should do some internal cleanup now and then without using GitHub.